# How to return a Date value from JSON to Google Visualization API

Tags: json, date, datatable, google-visualization

is there a way to retrieve date value from JSON in Google Visualization API?
Here is the snipplet for [playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#json_data_table) *please copy the code below into it*

**When you run the code you won't have anything in result.  you should remove the quotes from the date value I marked with comment in order to retrieve result.**

```
function drawVisualization() {
var JSONObject = {
cols:
    [
        {id: 'header1', label: 'Header1', type: 'string'},
        {id: 'header2', label: 'Header2', type: 'date'}
    ],
rows: 
    [
        {
            c:
                [
                    {v: 'Value1'}, 
                    {v: "new Date(2010, 3, 28)"}  // <= This is the format I receive from WebService
                ]
        },
        {
            c:
                [
                    {v: 'Value2'},
                    {v: new Date(2010, 3, 28)} // <=This is the format Google API accepts
                ]
        }
    ]
};

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(JSONObject, 0.5);

visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
visualization.draw(data, {'allowHtml': true});
}
```

Comment: I know this is a pretty old question but I have the same problem and you might help. This is my json `[["Date(2015,6,1)",9,218.0],["Date(2015,7,1)",10,497.5],["Date(2015,8,1)",13,317.5],["Date(2015,9,1)",29,1572.0],["Date(2015,10,1)",34,480.0],["Date(2015,11,1)",20,387.0],["Date(2016,0,1)",34,836.0],["Date(2016,1,1)",29,957.5],["Date(2016,2,1)",2,1250.0],["Date(2016,3,1)",2,793.5],["Date(2016,10,1)",3,801.0],["Date(2016,11,1)",2,756.5],["Date(2017,1,1)",2,410.0]]` and I get Uncaught Error: Type mismatch. Value Date(2015,6,1) does not match type date in column index 0.

Answer (score 9):

I just ran into this problem myself, so I thought I'd paste the answer from the google api documentation, located here http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/dev/implementing_data_source.html#jsondatatable

"JSON does not support JavaScript Date values (for example, "new Date(2008,1,28,0,31,26)"; the API implementation does. However, the API does now support a custom valid JSON representation of dates as a string in the following format: Date(year, month, day[,hour, minute, second[, millisecond]]) where everything after day is optional, and months are zero-based."

Answer (score 1):

I was running into same problem and above solution did not work. After searching for hours I found following post and the solution in there worked.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-visualization-api/SCDuNjuo7xo/ofAOTVbZg7YJ

Do not include "new" in the json string so it will be just:
    v:"Date(2009, 9, 28)"

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the quote is not at the correct place in your snippet `"new Date(2010, 3, 28")`
Write instead `"new Date(2010, 3, 28)"`

Json format does not accept javascript object so the server return a string. 
JSON knows only numbers, boolean constants, string, null, vector and 'object' (much more a dictionnary).

I suppose that you have to perform an eval() of the returned string (do not forget to check inputs).

Another alternative is to use a Regex to extract the fields something like `/new Date\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+)\)/` will work.

Comment: eval() is one of the solution. What I found before reading your answer, VGE, is to iterate over the dates and create a new Date(data.row[i].c[0].v) (the date is the first serie). I of course had the date formated in string so the new Date() understands it.

Comment: Sorry Marcel, I didn't see your comment before.  Neither EVAL nor manipulation of entire data are elegant solution.

Comment: @VGE thanks for the point out quote.  It was a simple typo.  I updated that on question