# new Date into Array php

Tags: php, date, google-visualization, json

For Google Visualization I coded the JSON by hand (Messy I know) I did not think about `'`'s in `NAME_TEAM` which has recently come about an issue as my first team name was entered with an apostrophe. I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262826/how-do-you-deal-with-single-quote-in-persons-names-in-php-javascript) and tried to implement php `json_encode`. I am having an issue with the dates. The `new Date` works fine in the old messy json format, however I get an error `Fatal error: Class 'Date'` when I try use anything similar for the Json_encode version. The format must be date for the visualization api to understand the values.

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
$dateArray = explode('-', $row['THE_DATE']);
$year = $dateArray[0];
$month = $dateArray[1] - 1;
$day = $dateArray[2];
$dataArray[] = "[new Date ($year, $month, $day),  {$row['ORANGE']}, {$row['GREEN']}, '{$row['NAME_TEAM']}']";


$itemOutput[] = array(
new Date($year, $month, $day),
$row['ORANGE_SCORE'],
$row['GREEN_SCORE'],
$row['NAME_TEAM'],
);
}
echo "data.addRows(" . json_encode($itemOutput) . ");" ;
```

**Data Table creation**

```
  function drawDashboard() {
         //var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo json_encode($itemOutput, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>);
            data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
            data.addColumn('number', 'ORANGE_SCORE');
            data.addColumn('number', 'GREEN_SCORE');
            data.addColumn('string', 'NAME_TEAM');

       //   data.addRows(<?php echo '[' . implode(',', $dataArray) . ']'; ?>);
```

**ARRAY FORMAT**

```
{"c":[
   {"Date":"new Date(2013, 9, 19)"},
   {"ORANGE_SCORE":14},
   {"GREEN_SCORE":7},
   {"NAME_TEAM":"Trigon"}]
},
```

Comment: `new Date ($year, $month, $day)` is not actually valid JSON. You're constructing literal Javascript source code instead of JSON. You should be encoding the date in JSON as regular string, then post-process it in Javascript to make it a Javascript object.

Comment: I should store my date as a string e.g.`"new Date (2013, 8, 14)"` how would this alter how I approach the input into the visualization.DataTable' `data.addRows(<?php json_encode($itemOutput) ?>);` I have added extra code to the initial question, showing where the JSON is integrated

Comment: Helpful question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638137/how-to-return-a-date-value-from-json-to-google-visualization-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Date objects in JSON; the only way to transmit dates is via strings, but the `DataTable.addRows` method does not parse strings into Date objects, so you will have to convert to the full JSON structure to make this work.  Here's an example:

```
$itemOutput = array(
    'cols' => array(
        array('type' => 'date', 'label' => 'Date'),
        array('type' => 'number', 'label' => 'ORANGE_SCORE'),
        array('type' => 'number', 'label' => 'GREEN_SCORE'),
        array('type' => 'string', 'label' => 'NAME_TEAM')
    ),
    'rows' => array()
);

foreach ($data as $row) {
    $dateArray = explode('-', $row['THE_DATE']);
    $year = $dateArray[0];
    $month = $dateArray[1] - 1;
    $day = $dateArray[2];

    $itemOutput['rows'][] = array('c' => array(
        array('v' => "Date($year, $month, $day)"),
        array('v' => $row['ORANGE_SCORE']),
        array('v' => $row['GREEN_SCORE']),
        array('v' => $row['NAME_TEAM'])
    ));
}
```

Then in javascript:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo json_encode($itemOutput, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>);
```

Answer (score 2):

If case 1 or 2, What do you want?

result is Case 2.

[result link](http://gnuhacker.cafe24.com/qna/24992408.php)

[source link](http://gnuhacker.cafe24.com/qna/24992408.phps)

```
<?
/***
  CREATE TABLE `24992408` (
`THE_DATE` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT DATE ,
`ORANGE` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`ORANGE_SCORE` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
`GREEN` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`GREEN_SCORE` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
`NAME_TEAM` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
INSERT INTO `24992408` (
`THE_DATE` ,
`ORANGE` ,
`ORANGE_SCORE` ,
`GREEN` ,
`GREEN_SCORE` ,
`NAME_TEAM`
)
VALUES (
  '2014-07-28' , '1', '1', '1', '2', 'NAME_TEAM'
);
***/
$host = "localhost";
$name = "user";
$db = "db";
$password ="password";

function confirm_query($watever){
    global $connection;
    if (!$watever) {
        die("Database query failed! " . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
}
function select_query(){
  global $connection;
  $query  = "SELECT * FROM `24992408` ";
  $admin_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
  confirm_query($admin_set);
  return $admin_set;
}
$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $name, $password, $db); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($admin_set = select_query());

$dateArray = explode('-', $row['THE_DATE']);
$year =  $dateArray[0];          //echo $year;    //2014
$month = $dateArray[1] - 1;      //echo $month;    //6
$day = $dateArray[2];            //echo $day;     //28

// IN PUT
//$date1 =  Date('Ymd',strtotime(sprintf('%04d%02d%02d',$year, $month, $day) ) ); //case 1
$date1 = "new Date ($year, $month, $day)";                                        //case 2

$dataArray[] = "[$date1,  {$row['ORANGE']}, {$row['GREEN']}, '{$row['NAME_TEAM']}']";
$itemOutput[] = array(  $date1,   $row['ORANGE_SCORE'],   $row['GREEN_SCORE'],  $row['NAME_TEAM']   );

echo "data.addRows(" . json_encode($dataArray) . ");" ;

// OUT PUT
//data.addRows(["[20140628, 1, 2, 'NAME_TEAM']"]);                                          // case 1 output
//data.addRows(["[new Date (2014, 6, 28), 1, 2, 'NAME_TEAM']"]);                            // case 2 output
?>
```